# How to return another view with its own url after login instead of loading inside same login page? MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to redirect to welcome page and it should show/hide html elements according to user type. I have written `return View("Welcome", adminvar);` but it returns the Welcome page inside login URL.

Upon refresh it shows popup warning of form resubmission. I want to redirect to Welcome page. I tried this

```
return RedirectToAction("Welcome" , adminvar);
```

but it's not working.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(tbl_Admin adminObj)
{ 
        studentDBEntities db = new studentDBEntities();
        var adminvar = db.tbl_Admin.Where(x => x.Email == adminObj.Email && x.Password == adminObj.Password).Select(s=> new tbl_AdminVM {
              AdminId = s.AdminId,
               Email = s.Email,
               Name = s.Name,
               Password = s.Password,
               Type = s.Type
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (adminvar != null)
        {
            
            /* return RedirectToAction("Welcome" , adminvar);*/
            return View("Welcome", adminvar);
        }
        else 
        {
            return View();
        }
}

public ActionResult Welcome()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome Admin - Admin Account Page";
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@if (Model.Type)
{
    <center><p>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Management", "ListAdmin")</p></center>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are returning Welcome View to the login method that will render welcome view content on login page and will not be redirected to welcome page.

What you can do is, after successful login, redirect to Welcome Action.

```
return RedirectToAction("Welcome", new { userType = adminvar.Type });
```

And modify Welcome action as below

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string userType)
```

Inside Welcome action get the value of usertype and send it to Welcome view using Viewbag.

```
ViewBag.userType = userType;
```

Use the value of ViewBag.userType on Welcome Page to show/hide html elements.

Answer (score 0):

You Can redirect to action

```
return RedirectToAction(“ActionName”,”ControllerName”);
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction(“~/ControllerName/ActionName”);
```